# How to check if the Mobile Phone has used Google Maps at least once

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am currently creating an app that has geolocation feature in it. However, I found out that the geolocation using google maps v3 will not work if Google Maps has not been open at least once on the phone. I have tried that and it is true. Is there a way to check if the geolocation in a phone is ready to use? Or if it is not I can just pop an alert that the user needs to use Google Maps to access the feature of Geolocation? Or maybe instead of making the user open Google Maps first is there another workaround on this? Thanks for those who will answer. 
:)

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean the JavaScript v3 API or the Android v2 API?

Comment: the javascript v3 api sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use the Google Maps JavaScript v3 API to use geolocation in a web page. The HTML5 Rocks site has a good introduction on using `navigator.geolocation` here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/geolocation/trip_meter/

Of note, there are some details on error handling that may be useful in troubleshooting your problem.

```
window.onload = function() {
   var startPos;
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      // same as above
   }, function(error) {
      alert('Error occurred. Error code: ' + error.code);
      // error.code can be:
      //   0: unknown error
      //   1: permission denied
      //   2: position unavailable (error response from locaton provider)
      //   3: timed out
   });
 };
```

Comment: Hi Sir. Currenty I am using PhoneGap because I am creating an app. I am using Google Maps api v3 because I am showing a map to the user. However, is the [Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) from Google Maps V3 is different from the example you gave me? Thanks!

Comment: The geolocation part in my example and in the Maps API v3 link you mention both use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(..)`. The difference is that the Maps example puts the location on a map. Can you provide the error code that you are seeing?

Comment: When I run the app, it shows the error on the logcat `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lat' of null", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#map (12)` Thanks.